# Is it possible css display:block after jquery display:none?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here is in jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/6vzkr4wt/15/

All works, if do not use jquery. Make browser screen at least `737px` and can see `<div id="menu">Menu Menu Menu</div>`. If change browser screen less than `737px`, then do not see `<div id="menu">Menu Menu Menu</div>`.

But the problem is after following actions:

1) Make browser screen less than `737px`

2) Click on `<div id="show_menu">Show menu</div>`, see `<div id="menu">Menu Menu Menu</div>`

3) Click outside `<div id="menu">Menu Menu Menu</div>` and `<div id="menu">Menu Menu Menu</div>` disappears. So far ok.

4) Here is problem. Make browser screen at least `737px` and do not see `<div id="menu">Menu Menu Menu</div>`

As I understand the execution of jquery code prevents it. What solution, please? Only with jquery to detect browser width and to show/hide `id="menu"`? With CSS not possible?

And below is code

```js
$(document).mouseup(function(e) {
  if (!$('#menu').is(e.target) && $('#menu').has(e.target).length === 0) {
    $("#menu").css("display", "none");
  }
});
$("#show_menu").click(function() {
  $("#menu").css("display", "block");
});
```

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 736px) {
  #menu {
    display: none;
  }
  #show_menu {
    display: block;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 737px) {
  #menu {
    display: block;
  }
  #show_menu {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="show_menu">Show menu</div>
<div id="menu">Menu Menu Menu</div>
```

Thanks for advises. Here `https://jsfiddle.net/6vzkr4wt/27/` is working as necessary. Will try to implement the same only with css.

And here https://jsfiddle.net/rauw6zyk/8/ example how to do it only with css (must use `tabindex="1"`. May be someone knows better solution.

```
<span class="span3" tabindex="1">Hide Me</span>
<span class="span2" tabindex="1">Show Me</span>
<p class="alert" >Some alarming information here</p>


body {
  display: block;
}
.span3:focus ~ .alert {
  display: none;
}
.span2:focus ~ .alert {
  display: block;
}
.alert{display:none;}
```

Comment: Usually you put `!important` in media query that should ignore jQuery code. Or instead let jQuery add some classes to element, that will work only on certain media widths

Comment: You can achieve this with the nasty "!important" or by toggling class names with javascript. But my suggestion would be: "Remove the jquery all together, and go full css."

Answer (score 0):

You can use $(window).width(), $(window).height() to find width & Height of window with jquery and make a check before $("#menu").css("display", "block");

```
$("#show_menu").click(function(){
  var w=$(window).width();
  if(w<=736){//Less then & equals to 736px 
   // don't do anything
  }
  else{//More then 736px
    $("#menu").css("display", "block");
  }
});
```